# Add Description to an Azure Pipeline YAML That Displays In The List Of Jobs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In addition to builds and deploys, I am a have a folder in my Azure DevOps Pipelines view for Admin Toolbox, with various commands that only our admins have access to, like "Create Tenant".

The names of the jobs have a good bit of context, but I would like to be able to add more, some sort of multiline description text beneath the job name.

Any ideas how to do something like this?  For now it is all in our wiki, but it would be nice to have just a little more context I can add to this view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible. The only thing I can think of that you can do is if the pipelines are defined using yaml is to add the multiline description at the top of the file and comment it out. That way, individuals who have access to these pipelines can click edit and see the multi-line description there